# Yocto recipe fails to install npm package

Tags: npm, yocto

I have a recipe that installed some NPM packages that worked on an older version of Yocto.

After upgrading to sumo, the recipe fails with the following error:
installnpmpackages/0.0.1-r0/temp/run.do_compile.7272: npm: not found
| WARNING: exit code 127 from a shell command.

I tried using the developer shell and NPM does work in that case.

The do_compile from the recipe:

```
do_compile() {
        # Create a working directory
        mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}/scratch

        # changing the home directory to the working directory, the .npmrc will be created in this directory
        export HOME=${WORKDIR}/scratch

        # configure cache to be in working directory
        npm set cache ${WORKDIR}/scratch/npm_cache

        # clear local cache prior to each compile
        npm cache clear

        # compile and install node modules in source directory
        cd ${WORKDIR}/scratch
        npm --arch=${TARGET_ARCH} --verbose install node-gyp
        npm --arch=${TARGET_ARCH} --verbose install connect
        npm --arch=${TARGET_ARCH} --verbose install socket.io
        #npm --arch=${TARGET_ARCH} --verbose install sqlite3
        #npm --arch=${TARGET_ARCH} --verbose install serialport
        npm --arch=${TARGET_ARCH} --verbose install express
        npm --arch=${TARGET_ARCH} --verbose install csv
        npm --arch=${TARGET_ARCH} --verbose install md5

        # clear local cache before we package. No need to copy over all this cache stuff; just need the modules.
        npm cache clear
}
```

Note sqlite3 and serialport are commented out as they did not work on the previous version.

What needs to be changed with sumo (vs morty) for NPM to function in a recipe?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple solution.

I created individual recipes using devtool add.

Here is the command used to create a recipe for the serialport npm module:

```
devtool add "npm://registry.npmjs.org;name=serialport;version=7.1.4"
```

Comment: Hey Dan. How will we add the package into OS? i have seen we can deploy it using devtool deploy. but cant we add this package into bblayers? like we do with other packages like python?

Comment: iam getting ERROR: URL: 'npm://registry.npmjs.org/;name=sqlite3;version=5.0.2' is missing the required parameter 'Parameter 'package' required'

Comment: I've got the same error as @krishna, did anyone found a solution?

Comment: @alex88, just append package=sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering to @Hsn comment as my account is new and I don't have 50 reputation.

If you are able to add a recipe with devtool and it worked, you can use devtool as well to finish working on the recipe and tell devtool in which meta you want to put the recipe like :

```
devtool finish recipe_name meta-destination
```

And in order to put it into your final OS rootfs, you need to add it to your image bb file, for example : image-dev.bb :

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "recipe_name"
```

Make sure also that the meta which holds your recipe is present in your bblayers.conf.